# Fail to retrieve a setupIntent because stripe.paymentIntents is undefined

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Following this guide(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/updating) to collect payment details with **Stripe checkout**, but it all fails in the step 4, because stripe.setupIntents is undefined.

Does anyone know what can be possibly wrong?

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_key_here");

 ...   

case "checkout.session.completed":

  if (event.data.object.setup_intent) {

    if (stripe.setupIntents) {
      const setupIntent = stripe.setupIntents.retrieve(
        event.data.object.setup_intent
      );
```

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property   'retrieve' of undefined

Comment: Are you using a version of `stripe-node` that is >= [v7.4.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/releases/tag/v7.4.0)?

Comment: which is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not check for the `stripe.setupIntents` instead assign the checkout session value to a variable like:

```
const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(your_payload);
```

and check `if (checkoutSession)` and for a good practice store `checkoutSession.payment_intent` in db